# Python TKinter text variable

Tags: python, tkinter

I get this error :
mySocket.send ( userInput )
TypeError: must be string or buffer, not instance

```
userInput = StringVar()
e = Entry(gui, textvariable=userInput)
e.pack()

def sendPacket():
mySocket = socket.socket (socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
mySocket.connect ( ( 'CENSORED', 2727 ) )
mySocket.send ( userInput )
```

Answer (score 1):

My tkinter is a bit rusty, but I think it's a simple oversight -- you need to call the `StringVar.get()` method to return it as an actual string, rather than referencing the `StringVar` object instance.

```
mySocket.send ( userInput.get() )
```